# I created a Azure App to use Graph, but keeps getting error pop-up "Approval required"

Tags: azure, graph

I followed the guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet-core, leverage sample code (ASP.NET Core MVC) from the GitHub repo of this guide.
But when I debug or published to Azure, keeps getting error "Approval required".
[image]
I need to sign out current user and sign in again, then the error is gone.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First make sure that your users are in the same tenant.
2. Then you should "grant admin consent for Microsoft" at your API permissions.
   [image]

Comment: How to check if my users are in the same tenant. For now, the users' account email may be 2: abc.com & xxx.abc.com.

Comment: And "Grant admin consent for Microsoft" my side is the same as you, checked and in grey

Comment: My account does not have permission. You need to log in wiith AAD admin account. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Lb3.png)

Comment: Are you suggesting me to ask AAD admin to click this "Grant admin consent for Microsoft" for me?

Comment: Applying for it from the ADD Admin, will come back later if it works, thanks in advance!

Comment: So far, the error has gone, thanks a lot!